# expect script change password prompted over ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

Currently I have a bash script that uses expect in it while doing some things over ssh. It looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#some bash stuff here
...
/usr/bin/expect -c '
    spawn somescript.sh
    expect "password:"
    send "$PASSWD"
'
...
```

somescript.sh does commands to a remote server over ssh, but now my login requires a change of password. I've tried

```
/usr/bin/expect -c '
    spawn somescript.sh
    expect "password:"
    send "$PASSWD"
    expect "current password"
    send "$PASSWD"
    expect "new password"
    send "$NEWPASSWD"
'
```

but I get an error saying:

```
WARNING: Your password has expired.\n Password change required but 
no TTY available.
```

Answer (score 3):

So, `somescript.sh` makes an `ssh` connection and then you get an error about TTY not being available.

Try `-t` option!

From [ssh man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1#ssh):

```
-t   Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbi-
     trary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be
     very useful, e.g., when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
     options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be resolved by directly connecting to the box using `ssh` (ie not in a script).

Do that, and it'll prompt you to change your password. Do so, and the error will go away.

Comment: This thread is about using expect for automation.  Your answer is not helpful.  -1

Comment: @JasonLeMonier - the question is about why expect fails, and it sounds like he thought it might be to do with expect - it's not... It's because his password needed to be changed, and the easy way to fix that problem was to connect normally using ssh.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you are trying run `ssh user@server passwd` but because your password expired you have to change it first. Probably when you run expect as `spawn user@server` it will ask you for password change and it will works.